# What is the meaning of directional derivative for a linear function $f(x) = ax$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

So the [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) is defined as,

$$f_d(x) = \lim_{ s \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+sd) - f(x)}{s}$$

If $f(x) = ax$, then $f_d(x) = a\cdot d, d \in \mathbb{R}$

But why does this make sense? What is the interpretation of $f_d(x)$?

My rate of change/slope is a constant $a$ no matter where I am on the $x$-axis.

So why is it that increasing $d$ will increase my directional derivative, when the slope is constant throughout?

Comment: The slope is not constant. You can think of it like this, if you travel one "$s$" then the actual displacement is $d$. It is kind of a change of units. This makes sense if you remember that one can express the directional derivative in terms of the total derivative as $$f_d(x)=Df(x)[d].$$

Comment: The directional derivative always satisfies $f_{td}(x) = t f_d(x)$ for $t \ge 0$, so one can just take $d$ to be a unit vector. In that case, since $f$ is linear, $f_d(x)$ is the change in $f$ when you 'move' from $x$ to $x+d$. Since $f$ is linear, this change is independent of $x$.

Comment: @copper.hat I think you should make this an answer. It's not getting much clearer than that :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with directional derivative.  Directional derivatives are defined for functions of 2 or more variables.  If you have a function $f(\mathbf{x})$ where $ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^n$ , and you have a unit direction  $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbf{R}^n$ , then the direction derivative of the function $f$ along $\mathbf{u}$ is defined as $$ D_u f = \displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0} \dfrac{ f(\mathbf{x} + t \mathbf{u}) - f(\mathbf{x}) }{ t } $$  And there is a theorem that states that $$D_u f = \nabla f \cdot \mathbf{u} $$ where $\nabla f $ is the gradient of the function $f$.

Comment: @HosamHajeer the theorem holds when $f$ is (Frechet) differentiable. As a conterexample, consider $f(x)=|x|$, for which all directional derivatives exist at $x=0$.

Comment: In fact, the directional derivative of any convex function $f:\mathbb R ^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ at any point in the interior of its domain exists.

Answer (score 0):

To understand directional derivatives, let us compare it with **Fréchet derivative**, commonly used in real analysis and calculus.

Let $f$ be real-valued function defined on an inner-product linear space $V$, then the *Fréchet derivative* at $x\in V$  is defined as a vector $ \nabla f(x) \in V$ such that the directional derivative for all $d\in V$, can be written as:

$$f_d(x) = \lim_{ s \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+sd) - f(x)}{s}=  \langle \nabla f(x),d \rangle \forall d \in V$$

From this, for the case $V=\mathbb R$, you can see that

1. Even for **a univariate function**, the directional derivative may exist in all directions at a point (it is Gateaux differentiable), **but the Fréchet derivative may  not**, for example, consider $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$ (it is not Fréchet differentiable, commonly called differentiable in real analysis). In fact, for (Fréchet) differentiable functions, at any $x\in \mathbb R$ we have:
   $$f_d(x)=f'(x)\times d$$

whit $d=y-x$ for any $y \in \mathbb R$. In particular, for a linear function $f(x)=ax$, $f_d(x)=a\times d$.

2. The directional derivative is an asymptotic **amount of change** of $f$ by moving along the given direction $d$, while the Fréchet derivative (if exists) is an asymptotic  **rate of change** for one unit of increment at $x \in \mathbb R$; i.e., $d=(x+1)-x=1$.

For $V=\mathbb {R}^n$, $\nabla f(x)$ is broadly called the *gradient* vector at $x$, given by

$$\nabla f(x)=\left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1}, \dots, \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_n} \right)^T$$

The same interpretation for $V=\mathbb {R}^n$ cannot be presented for all $d$ with $\|d\|=1$ as the norm induced by the common inner product $ \langle x,y \rangle =x^{T}y$ is Euclidean. However, for $d=(x+e_i)-x$ again we have:

$$f_{d=e_i}(x)=\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_i}\times 1$$

where $e_i$ is a vector whose $i$th element is 1, and other elements are 0.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I think what you are calling Gâteauy differentiable is typically called semi-differentiable. The classical directional derivative is defined with $s\rightarrow 0$ instead of $s\rightarrow 0^+$ and is a slightly stronger notion.